# Rename python subpackage, mark old name as deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.5

I have a python package which has the following directory structure

```
package/
├── __init__.py
└── subpackage_A/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── moduleA.py
    └── moduleB.py
```

Now I want to change the name of the `subpackage_A` to `subpackage_B` while keeping the old name available as otherwise a lot of scripts would break. So this should be possible:

```py
from package.subpackage_B import moduleA
from package.subpackage_B.moduleB import ClassB

# This should, if possible, display a deprecation warning
from package.subpackage_A import moduleA
```

I have tried to simply import the new package in a module named `subpackage_A`, but this does not work:

```py
# File: package/subpackage_A.py
# This does not work:
from package.subpackage_B import *  # Import everything from the new module

# This is also not working:
sys.modules[__name__] = __import__('package.subpackage_A')
```

The first version leads to an `ModuleNotFoundError` if a script tries to import `moduleA` from the old location:

```py
from package.subpackage_A import moduleA
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.subpackage_A.moduleA'
```

How can I rename the module while not breaking backward compatibility? The solution should work with python 3.5 and above.

Comment: What errors are you getting with the `import *` solution?

Comment: Scripts which try to `moduleA` form the old localtion get a `ModuleNotFoundError`: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.subpackage_A.moduleA'`. I've added the error message in my question above.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python 3.7+ you can use module level `__getattr__`s defined in [PEP562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/).

You'd rename your subpackageA to subpackageB, then in your `package/__init__.py` have something like the following

```
from . import subpackageB
from warnings import warn

def __getattr__(name):
    if name == 'subpackageA':
        warn('subpackageA has been renamed to subpackageB')
        return subpackageB
    raise AttributeError('No module named ' + name)
```

Then when using your package

```
>>> from package import subpackageB
>>> from package import subpackageA
/path/to/package/__init__.py:5: UserWarning: subpackageA has been renamed subpackageB
  warn('subB has been renamed subA')
>>> subpackageA == subpackageB
true
>>>
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution! Is something similar possible with python 3.5/3.6?

Comment: You could potentially make something work with [import hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) (and [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/)) but it'd be unpleasant. I'll try and get something working if I get a chance.

Comment: Yea, I looked at import hooks but for me the docs where to abstract to get an idea on where to start...

Comment: This works when using `from package import subpackageA`, but seems to fail when using `import package.subpackageA` (defaults to the normal import error). Any good way to make it work in that case? I attempted a few variations in the different level package init's, but couldn't seem to get it working. An ideal solution would be one that you can add to a single package init, and it handles all variations (e.g., `from package import subpackageA`, `import package.subpackageA`, `from package.subpackageA import SomeClass`, etc).

Comment: You could maybe create a `subpackageA/__init__.py` file that did the `from package import subpackageA` then set `__all__` to `dir(subpackageA)` and did some similar `__getattr__` mangling to redirect to the imported package? I don't have a 3.7+ installation on my machine to test at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `subpackage_B/__init__.py` does not import `moduleA` and `moduleB` so `import *` imports nothing.

Either use explicit imports:

```
from .subpackage_B import moduleA, moduleB
```

Or modify `subpackage_B/__init__.py` to do the imports explicitly:

```
from . import moduleA, moduleB
```

---

Regarding raising a warning if subpackage_A is used: you can simply trigger it. Inside `subpackage_A`:

```
import warnings

warnings.warn('The name subpackage_A is deprecated. Please use subpackage_B')

from .subpackage_B import *
```

Comment: After some fideling about the different import statements this seems to work in my (limited) testcases.